# php foreach multidimensional array issue

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I use a multidimensional array in a foreach loop, but i dont get the right results back.

array

```
$mainarray = array( 

    array('field_name'      => 'xx', 
          'email_label'     => 'xxxx', 
          'validation_type' => 'xxxxx',
          'validation_msg'  => 'xxxxxx'),

    array('field_name'      => 'xx', 
          'email_label'     => 'xxxx', 
          'validation_type' => 'xxxxx',
          'validation_msg'  => 'xxxxxx'),

            // more ....
}
```

foreach loop

```
foreach($mainarray as $fieldarray){
    foreach($fieldarray as $key => $value){     
        $body .= $value['email_label'].' - '. $value['field_name']; 
    }
}
```

i need the value's of the key called email_label and field_name, but i dont get the right results back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your code that appends to `$body` accesses indexes of `$value`, your original code was effectively written to work on a three-level array.

If your array is structured as you've posted, you don't need the inner `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($mainarray as $fieldarray) {    
    $body .= $fieldarray['email_label'].' - '. $fieldarray['field_name']; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need one loop for this:

```
foreach($mainarray as $fieldarray){
    $body .= $fieldarray['email_label'].' - '. $fieldarray['field_name']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
foreach($mainarray as $fieldarray){
    $body .= $fieldarray['email_label'].' - '. $fieldarray['field_name']; 
}
```